# AS400/DB2 - Converting integer based dates and times to a timestamp?

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I have 4 pieces of user input: `startDate`, `endDate`, `startTime`, `endTime`.

The dates and times in the database are setup differently than anything I have used before. The dates are the number of days since December 31st, 1900. So an integer. For example, October 16, 2015, would be represented as 41927.

The times are in ISO format - with no decimals, so also an integer. So 08:00:00 would be 80000. 19:00:00 would be 190000. It's basically hhmmss - but sometimes you only have one h.

I am trying to filter the dates and times into ranges. On one day where I'm just looking at times this works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM database WHERE day = 41927 AND time > startTime and time < endTime
```

It also works if you're strictly looking at days:

```
SELECT * FROM database WHERE day > startDate AND day < endDate
```

The problem comes in when you need to find items between two dates on two times because it will filter out anything not between those two times on every day. I know there is a way to create a timestamp, but I'm struggling to put it together within the query using two integers.

What kind of options do I have to tackle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this with simple arithmetic:

```
select date('1900-12-31') + col days
```

However, I suspect the real date start date is 1899-12-31.  That is the date used by Excel (so day 1 is 1900-01-01).

EDIT:

Oops, left out the seconds.  One method is:

```
select timestamp(date('1900-12-31') + coldays days) +
       (floor(coltime / 10000) * 60*60 +
        mod(floor(coltime / 100)) * 60
        mod(coltime, 100)
       ) seconds
```

Comment: Ok great that solves the days, the only problem is the seconds. They aren't actually in seconds - they are ISO format without decimals. So 07:00 is 25200 seconds, but I have it in the format '70000'. I guess the best way is to break it into it's respective digits and do some multiplication. And, for whatever reason, the origin time is actually 1900-12-31, I have no idea why it was setup that way.

Comment: To your edit: Yep that works great! Just a few minor syntax things if someone else comes across this, it should be: select timestamp(date('1900-12-31') + coldays days) +
       (floor(coltime / 10000) * 60*60 +
        mod(floor(coltime / 100),100) * 60
        mod(coltime, 100)
       ) seconds

Comment: @Kiresays . . . I fixed the logic.  Thank you.

Comment: No doubt 1900-12-31 was chosen specifically to sidestep the famous "Excel date bug" (inherited from Lotus 1-2-3), wherein 1900 is incorrectly considered a leap year.

Answer (score 2):

While you have a working answer (from your comment)...

```
select  * from mytable
where CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
         < timestamp(date('1900-12-31') + coldays days) 
              + (floor(coltime / 10000) * 60*60 
              + mod(floor(coltime / 100),100) * 60 mod(coltime, 100) )
```

you may find it doesn't perform very well as the function usage on a column in the `WHERE` clause limit the usability of an standard index.  At best, you get a full index scan and at worse you'd get a full table scan.

Two options
1) One recent versions of the OS (v6.1 and higher) you can create a derived index.

```
create index mytsidx on mytable 
  (timestamp(date('1900-12-31') + coldays days) 
             + (floor(coltime / 10000) * 60*60 
             + mod(floor(coltime / 100),100) * 60 mod(coltime, 100) )     
                seconds )
```

2) On older versions, you'd want to convert your incoming timestamp into parts and compare like so :

```
   select * from mytable
     where (strdays < coldays 
             or strdays = coldays and strtime <= coltime)
        and (enddays > coldays
              or enddays = coldays and endtime >= coltime)
```

If you go with option 1, I'd suggest a creating a UDF to handle the conversion.

```
   create index mytsidx on mytable (CONVERT_TO_TS(coldays,coltime));

   select * from mytable
     where CONVERT_TO_TS(coldays,coltime)
              between start_ts and end_ts;
```